# String Array from database to Bitmap

Tags: android, sql, bitmap

In my database I have a row that store links from images from the internet.
In the code below, I have taken the name and put in a ListView for each row.
Now the KEY_LINK hold the links of the images, how I convert this array to a Bitmap and the change for each KEY_NAME in the ListView?

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void populate(){
        Cursor cursor = entry.getAllRows();
        String[] from = new String[] {SQLHelper.KEY_NAME, SQLHelper.KEY_LINK};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2};
        SimpleCursorAdapter nameAdapter;
        nameAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.item_list, cursor, from, to);
        ListView mylist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mylist.setAdapter(nameAdapter);



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

android can not use url to set imageView.

the solution to your case is

for each Url String do this
1. create a HTTPGET request to KEY_LINK , this may in a AsyncTask
2. get the connection result. if you confirm it return a image, simply use this method:

```
    public final static Bitmap getImageFromUrl(final String paramURL) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    final Callable<Bitmap> task = new Callable<Bitmap>() {

        @Override
        public Bitmap call() throws Exception {
            {
                final URL uurl = new URL(paramURL);
                final HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) uurl.openConnection();

                final InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                final BufferedInputStream mBufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                final Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mBufferedInputStream);
                mBufferedInputStream.close();
                return mBitmap;
            }
        }
    };
    final Future<Bitmap> result = exec.submit(task);
    exec.shutdown();
    return result.get();
    }
```

then you get all image in local,so you can notify your adapter attached to ListView.
override your adapter `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`, according to position ,update your custom ListView item(TextView,ImageView) also.
there is a detail guide about how to create custom ListView.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Thats good, but i searched a little more, and found Universal Image Loader, it may suit my needs in that case

Comment: wow, wonderful.this project may also helpful for others [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: Anyway, I dont know if I ask here or make another question, but how do I get the contents from a database to a String Array, or a ArrayList?

Comment: I'm not familiar with handling database. but you can have a look at [Android show Data from Sqlite DB into Grid View](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2012/10/android-show-data-from-sqlite-db-into.html),simply change grid view to list view. and a full tutorial  **4.3 Database and Data Model** at [SQLite database](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

Comment: Thanks, im now using Universal Imagem Loader and I recomend it!

Comment: Unfortunately, I found that UIL in custom ListView has poor behavior. UIL 3-level cache didn't work at all. It download each image several times logged on  `UIL debug mode` and caused UI flash. In my case, image will not change frequently,  I only use it in initialization.